# Main.GamePanel is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) in java.awt.event.KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

I was doing a tutorial online because I wanted to make a 2d side scroller, and I got this exact error. I have googled it but came up with nothing. I tried looking for a typo and it looks clean, its not giving me an error anywere else in the code. I do not know where to start. If you could explaing to me what the error is and how i fix it then that would be amazing.

```
    package Main;


import GameState.GameStateManager;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener{
    public static final int WIDTH = 320;
    public static final int HIGHT = 240;
    public static final int SCALE = 2;

    //game thread

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
    private int FPS = 60;
    private long targetTime = 1000/FPS;
    //image        
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Graphics2D g;

    //game state manager
    private GameStateManager gsm;




    public GamePanel(){
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
    }
    public void addNotify(){
        super.addNotify();
        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            addKeyListener(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }   
    private void init() {
        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);     
        g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        running = true;
        gsm = new GameStateManager();

    }

        public void run(){
        init();
        long start, elapsed, wait;

        //game loop
          while(running) {

            start = System.nanoTime();
            update();
            draw();
            drawToScreen();
               elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;

               wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;

               try
               {
                   Thread.sleep(wait);
               }
               catch(Exception e) 
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }//end of try catch
          }







        }
        private void update()
        {
            gsm.update();
        }
        private void draw()
        {
            gsm.draw(g);
        }
        private void drawToScreen()
        {
            Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
            g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            g2.dispose();


        }




        public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent key) 
        {
         gsm.keyPressed(key.getKeyCode());
        }
        public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent key) 
        {
         gsm.keyReleased(key.getKeyCode());
        }




    }
```

Comment: You should check out [How to write key listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), [Interfaces and Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html) and [Key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), because they will solve the next problem you are about to run into...

Comment: Also would learn about object design principles, [Single Responsability Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html) , Your class GamePanel should only be one thing, not a keyListener or a Runnable, just to be a JPanel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  `KeyReleased(KeyEvent key)` method must start with small letter 'k' like `keyReleased(KeyEvent key)`. Java is case sensitive.

You may also required to override other methods of KeyListener interface.

Also add @Override annotation (as suggested by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels) to the method when you want to override a super method. That way IDE's will give you hint's while coding.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler error message tells you *exactly* what's wrong: your class implements the KeyListener interface but does not implement all the necessary methods of the interface. Solution: be sure to  implement all the necessary methods as per the KeyListener API. Also be sure to use the `@Override` annotation to make sure that your overrides are correct.

Having said that, I'm going to recommend that you *not* use KeyListeners for most key board input with Swing applications, that it is a low-level listener and should be avoided in favor of higher level constructs such as [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Also, Swing GUI's should avoid use of `update(...)` method overrides as that is more of an AWT construct.